# Why is this print only "false" instead of "false false"?

Tags: java, equals

```
class test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Object o1 = new Object();
        Object o2 = new Object();
        System.out.println(o1==o2 + " " + o1.equals(o2));
    }
}
```

I understand why both `o1==o2` and `o1.equals(o2)` are `false` but why is it only printing out  `"false"`, instead of `"false false"`?

Comment: Is it printing false true or just false?

Comment: It should print two boolean values separated by a space (specifically "false false"). If that's not the case, the output doesn't match your code. Have you saved your source files and cleaned the project?

Comment: Check if the code that you posted here is the one that you are executing. THis one prints false false

Comment: It prints false because `o1` is not equal to `o2 + " " + o1.equals(o2)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because the == used as expression to compare two parts.

Its comparing ***o1*** with a entire ***o2 + " " + o1.equals(o2)*** String.

I added spaces to better view it.

```
System.out.println(o1   ==       o2 + " " + o1.equals(o2));
```

if you want double false. Here is the modified println statement.

```
System.out.println((o1 == o2) + "    " + o1.equals(o2));
```

Answer (score 1):

K139 is correct, but let me explain why.  This is tricky at first glance but it all comes down to Operator Precedence.

See [Java API Operators Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

Additive operators `+` come before equality `==`

So `System.out.println(o1==o2 + " " + o1.equals(o2));`

Is more clearly being passed the arguement:
`o1 == (o2 + " " + o1.equals(o2))`

That is checking if `o1` is equivalent to a string like `"java.lang.Object@123a439b false"`, the result is `false`, and you see that as the only output.

Adding parenthesis around the first equivalency check causes the operations to be executed in the order you intended.

`System.out.println((o1==o2) + " " + o1.equals(o2));`

This yields: `false false`